# In VBA, For Loop outputs VALUE error for standard operation?

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, worksheet-function

So, after some lengthy debugging, I tracked down an inscrutable error coming from the very end of my last For loop. First, here is my code,

```
Function constant_covariance(inputs)

Dim c_matrix() As Variant
ReDim c_matrix(inputs.Rows.Count, inputs.Rows.Count)

Rs = inputs.Rows.Count
Cols = inputs.Columns.Count
If (Rs <> Cols) Then                    'Error if dimensions of range for covariance matrix not equal.
    MsgBox "Dimensions of range not equal; try again."
    Exit Function
End If

Sum = 0
For i = 1 To Rs     'This is to create my average correlation value.
    range1 = Range(inputs(1, i), inputs(1, i).End(xlDown))
    For j = 1 To Cols
        range2 = Range(inputs(1, j), inputs(1, j).End(xlDown))
        If Not (i = j) Then
            Sum = Sum + WorksheetFunction.Covar(range1, range2)
        End If
        Next j
Next i
avg_corr = Sum / Rs 'Average correlation value.

For i = 1 To Rs          'Regular correlation matrix, with only modification in last line before "End If".
    range1 = Range(inputs(1, i), inputs(1, i).End(xlDown))
    For j = 1 To Cols
        range2 = Range(inputs(1, j), inputs(1, j).End(xlDown))
        If (i = j) Then
            c_matrix(i, j) = WorksheetFunction.Var(range1)
        ElseIf Not (i = j) Then
            c_matrix(i, j) = (WorksheetFunction.Covar(range1, range2)) ^ 0.5 * avg_corr
        End If
    Next j
Next i

constant_covariance = (WorksheetFunction.Covar(range1, range2)) ^ 0.5 * avg_corr

End Function
```

At the very bottom, when I take the covariance of two input regions and raise it to the power of 0.5, and then multiply that by another variable, I get a `VALUE` error. Thing is, I put the same exact code as my function's output, just for testing purposes, and it works fine there.

Is there something wrong with my array that it doesn't like that overly complex operation being an input to one of its members? Would someone please explain what the source of my error is here?

Comment: These links may be relevant they centre on a different error handling behaviour between Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar and Application.Covar ( I have substituted CoVar in) https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/584913-application-vs-application-worksheetfunction.html   http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx

Comment: Changing my code to just application.covar didn't affect anything, though that is interesting reading.

Comment: What about assigning the result of your `Worksheet.Covar` function to an intermediate variable, then using that variable in the last computation? I've had to do this on a few occasions and had it work without quite understanding why.

Comment: Ok, next suggestion, `End(xlDown)` behaves differently when it is sitting on a single cell to when it sits at top or middle of a block.  So you are looping through rows, when the last row happens, i.e. you are at bottom of a range then `End(xlDown)` will drop all the way to the next non-empty cell or the bottom on the sheet!

Comment: @SMeaden That would seem possibly the culprit. Is there any way to get around the very last row screwing up my loop? Using `xlDown` is an incredibly useful method to grab regions, I'd hate to simply discard it.

@PeterT I will try your common-sense workaround shortly.